# HighChart IE9 z-index issue

Tags: internet-explorer-9, highcharts

I have a HTML select above the highchart control. The from and to fields are on top of the dropdown (see image). I've tried setting the z-index of the select and the chart container. Nothing seems to work. This only happens in IE. Any advice?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced yur example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HpNMA/

```
<select>
    <option>testtesttestetestetestestsetes</option>
    <option>testtesttestetestetestestsetes</option>
</select>
```

and problem doesn't appear in IE9.

Which version do you have? Could you update my example with your code?

Comment: Its worth mentioning that we are extending the select to be searchable using this plug in:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/searchabledropdown

Comment: So problem is with your additinal plugin, as I see, because standard controls are displayed correct.

Comment: You can see on the screenshot that only the from and to text boxes behave that way. The other chart controls (period buttons) remain behind the drop down. This leads me to beleave that the issue is with the from and to fields.

Comment: It is possible to recreate your example in the jsfiddle? (updating my example) with your source code?